# Determine what is being dragged from dragenter & dragover events

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I'm trying to use the HTML5 draggable API (though I realize it [has its problems](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html)). So far, the only showstopper I've encountered is that I can't figure out a way to determine what is being dragged when a `dragover` or `dragenter` event fires:

```
el.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
  // what is the draggable element?
});
```

I realize I could assume that it's the last element to fire a `dragstart` event, but... multitouch. I've also tried using `e.dataTransfer.setData` from the `dragstart` to attach a unique identifier, but apparently that data is [inaccessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer#getData()) from `dragover`/`dragenter`:

> This data will only be available once a drop occurs during the drop event.

So, any ideas?

**Update:** As of this writing, HTML5 drag-and-drop does not appear to be implemented in any major mobile browser, making the point about multitouch moot in practice. However, I'd like a solution that's guaranteed to work across any implementation of [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html), which does not appear to preclude multiple elements from being dragged simultaneously.

I've posted [a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089592/66226) below, but it's an ugly hack. I'm still hoping for a better answer.

Comment: normally you should be able to use the "this" property inside the function, which is linked to the object that fired the event.

Comment: @lgomezma No, `this` in a `dragenter`/`dragover` event handler points to the element that's being dragged over, not to the element being dragged. It's equal to `e.target`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/jWCSB/

Comment: I don't think Microsoft had multitouch in mind when they [originally designed and implemented drag-and-drop for IE 5](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html).

Comment: @JefferyTo I'm aware of that, but now that their design has been codified as a standard, I'd like to future-proof by working against the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html), not just existing implementations.

Comment: Filed this bug against the spec - https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=23486

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The short answer to my question turns out to be: No. The [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html) doesn't provide a reference to the element being dragged (called the "source node" in the spec) in the `dragenter`, `dragover`, or `dragleave` events.

Why not? Two reasons:

First, as Jeffery points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065803/determine-what-is-being-dragged-from-dragenter-dragover-events/11125533#comment14565009_11065803), the WHATWG spec is based on IE5+'s implementation of drag-and-drop, which predated multi-touch devices. (As of this writing, no major multi-touch browser implements HTML drag-and-drop.) In a "single-touch" context, it's easy to store a global reference to the current dragged element on `dragstart`.

Second, HTML drag-and-drop allows you to drag elements across multiple documents. This is awesome, but it also means that providing a reference to the element being dragged in every `dragenter`, `dragover`, or `dragleave` event wouldn't make sense; you can't reference an element in a different document. It's a strength of the API that those events work the same way whether the drag originated in the same document or a different one.

But the inability to provide serialized information to all drag events, except through `dataTransfer.types` (as described in my [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089592/66226) answer), is a glaring omission in the API. **I've [submitted a proposal for public data in drag events](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Jun/0221.html) to the WHATWG, and I hope you'll express your support.**

Comment: I had the same problem and came to the conclusion that the best bet here is to stick a custom mime type in the data transfer.  since the main purpose of the drag over function you provide is to stop the event I agree it requires some information on which to base this. for many purposes it seems fine to be able to say "the drag contains application/myapp and I can handle that so cancel the event".

Comment: I've seen your proposal link but I really don't know where I can read answers to this, or even express my support

Answer (score 82):

I wanted to add a very clear answer here so that it was obvious to everyone who wanders past here. It's been said several times in other answers, but here it is, as clear as I can make it:

## `dragover` DOES NOT HAVE THE RIGHTS to see the data in the drag event.

This information is only available during the DRAG_START and DRAG_END (drop).

The issue is it's not obvious at all and maddening until you happen to read deeply enough on the spec or places like here.

WORK-AROUND:

As a possible work-around I have added special keys to the DataTransfer object and tested those. For example, to improve efficiency I wanted to look up some "drop target" rules when my drag started instead of every time a "drag over" occurred. To do this I added keys identifying each rule onto the dataTransfer object and tested those with "contains".

```
ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types.includes("allow_drop_in_non_folders")
```

And things like that. To be clear, that "includes" is not a magic bullet and can become a performance concern itself. Take care to understand your usage and scenarios.

Comment: This is good advice if you don't have support IE/Edge. IE/Edge only allows two values as type: "text" or "url".

Comment: The workaround could even pass more data using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` ([poc](https://codepen.io/BuonOmo/pen/RZZbvZ)). Very inelegant though

Comment: I like clear answers that shout in my face. Easy to remember :D

Comment: Am I correct that this answer is outdated, at least partially? With [`DataTransfer.items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/items) one can at least check the MIME type of a dragged file in the `dragenter` event handler.  There's [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45471116/1483676) (far below) that mentions it.

Answer (score 14):

A (very inelegant) solution is to store a selector as a *type* of data in the `dataTransfer` object. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/eKHap/

The active lines here are

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'foo');
e.dataTransfer.setData('draggable', '');
```

Then in the `dragover` and `dragenter` events, `e.dataTransfer.types` contains the string `'draggable'`, which is the ID needed to determine which element is being dragged. (Note that browsers apparently require data to be set for a recognized MIME type like `text/html` as well in order for this to work. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.)

It's an ugly, ugly hack, and if someone can give me a better solution, I'll happily grant them the bounty.

**Update:** One caveat worth adding is that, in addition to being inelegant, the spec states that all data types will be converted to lower-case ASCII. So be warned that selectors involving capital letters or unicode will break. [Jeffery's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125533/66226) sidesteps this issue.

Comment: yes, faced the key turning lowercase for quite a while :(

Answer (score 7):

Given the current spec, I don't think there is any solution that isn't a "hack". [Petitioning](http://www.whatwg.org/mailing-list#specs) the WHATWG is one way to get this fixed :-)

Expanding on the "(very inelegant) solution" ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/eKHap/1/)):

- Create a global hash of all elements currently being dragged:

  ```
  var dragging = {};
  ```
- In the `dragstart` handler, assign a drag ID to the element (if it doesn't have one already), add the element to the global hash, then add the drag ID as a data type:

  ```
  var dragId = this.dragId;

  if (!dragId) {
      dragId = this.dragId = (Math.random() + '').replace(/\D/g, '');
  }

  dragging[dragId] = this;

  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', dragId);
  e.dataTransfer.setData('dnd/' + dragId, dragId);
  ```
- In the `dragenter` handler, find the drag ID among the data types and retrieve the original element from the global hash:

  ```
  var types = e.dataTransfer.types, l = types.length, i = 0, match, el;

  for ( ; i < l; i++) {
      match = /^dnd\/(\w+)$/.exec(types[i].toLowerCase());

      if (match) {
          el = dragging[match[1]];

          // do something with el
      }
  }
  ```

If you keep the `dragging` hash private to your own code, third-party code would not be able to find the original element, even though they can access the drag ID.

This assumes that each element can only be dragged once; with multi-touch I suppose it would be possible to drag the same element multiple times using different fingers...

---

**Update:** To allow for multiple drags on the same element, we can include a drag count in the global hash: http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/eKHap/2/

Comment: Ooph, it didn't occur to me that the *same element* could conceivably be dragged multiple times simultaneously. The spec doesn't appear to preclude it.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I've updated my answer to allow for multiple drags on the same element, but honestly I have no idea how the spec will change to allow for multi-touch.

Answer (score 5):

To check if it is a file use:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].kind
```

To check the type use:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].type
```

i.e. I want to allow only one single file jpg, png, gif, bmp

```
var items = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items;
var allowedTypes = ["image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/bmp"];
if (items.length > 1 || items["0"].kind != "file" || items["0"].type == "" || allowedTypes.indexOf(items["0"].type) == -1) {
    //Type not allowed
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem

Comment: I don't think `originalEvent` is populated in most of cases, even for Chrome.

Comment: @windmaomao I tested it with Chrome, Edge and Firefox and it works fine for all.

Comment: `evt.originaEvent` is for when you're using jQuery.  You might want to do something like `const evt = $evt.originalEvent;` to accommodate jQuery and carry on with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine what is being dragged when the drag starts and save this in a variable to use when the dragover/dragenter events are fired:

```
var draggedElement = null;

function drag(event) {
    draggedElement = event.srcElement || event.target;
};

function dragEnter(event) {
    // use the dragged element here...
};
```

Comment: I mentioned this in my question. The approach is untenable on multitouch devices, where multiple elements can be dragged simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

In the `drag` event, copy `event.x` and `event.y` to an object and set it as the value of an expando property on the dragged element.

```
function drag(e) {
    this.draggingAt = { x: e.x, y: e.y };
}
```

In the `dragenter` and `dragleave` events find the element whose expando property value matches the `event.x` and `event.y` of the current event.

```
function dragEnter(e) {
    var draggedElement = dragging.filter(function(el) {
        return el.draggingAt.x == e.x && el.draggingAt.y == e.y;
    })[0];
}
```

To reduce the number of elements you need to look at, you can keep track of elements by adding them to an array or assigning a class in the `dragstart` event, and undoing that in the `dragend` event.

```
var dragging = [];
function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', '');
    dragging.push(this);
}
function dragEnd(e) {
    dragging.splice(dragging.indexOf(this), 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/4bVhL/

Now, in theory this should work.  However, I don't know how to enable dragging for a touch device, so I wasn't able to test it.  This link is mobile formatted, but touch and slide didn't cause dragging to start on my android.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/gilly3/4bVhL/1/show/

**Edit:** From what I've read, it doesn't look like HTML5 draggable is supported on any touch devices.  Are you able to get draggable working on any touch devices?  If not, multi-touch wouldn't be an issue and you can resort to just storing the dragged element in a variable.

Comment: @Trevor - Really?  [My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/4bVhL/) works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @gilly3 How does your method work? I've not used a multi-touch device but I presume you can drag multiple objects at the same time. Is the element that last called the drag event guaranteed to be the element that first calls the drag enter event? (my wording is not the clearest but hopefully you know what I mean)

Comment: @Jules - I would *expect* that drag and dragenter would be called in immediate succession for the same element as you suggest in a multi-touch environment (that supports HTML5 draggable), and I would be surprised if that wasn't the case. **But,** I'd be more surprised if that was guaranteed (ie, defined that way by the spec). My method keeps an array of elements being dragged and searches for the element that is at the same position as the current event.  I know what position each dragged element is at because I update a custom property on the element in the `drag` event handler.

Comment: @gilly3 I see what you mean. Thinking about it, a dragenter would only be checked straight after a drag so there would be no reason to not call the dragenter immediately, before checking for any other drags.

Comment: @gilly3 The spec does guarantee that `drag` always fires before `dragenter` (the fact that it wasn't firing for me was due to a bug in a very specific version of Chrome). However, it doesn't guarantee that `x` and `y` will have consistent values. Overall, this is a clever response and I'm giving it a +1, but I don't think I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read on MDN, what you are doing is correct.

MDN lists some [recommended drag types](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types), such as text/html, but if none are suitable then just store the id as text using the 'text/html' type, or create your own type, such as 'application/node-id'.

Comment: As I say in the question: You can try to store the id as `text/html` data, but you can't access that data until the drop because of the security model. See [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#drag-data-store-mode), esp. "Protected mode."

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! Is this to give a visual cue if it is ok to drop? Could you at least try/catch in the dragenter event. When it comes to dropping, you have all the info available then and can then cancel the drop if it is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers are already explaining, the `data` set using [`DataTransfer.setData(format, data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) is not accessible by `dragenter` and `dragover` event handlers, whereas the `format` is accessible in the [`DataTransfer.types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/types) array. We can abuse this fact to put the data in the `format`.

Other than what the other answers explain, we can use the `format` not just to store individual attributes, but for actual JSON objects as well. From what I understand, the `format` will be converted to lower case and I'm not sure special characters will cause any trouble, so I'm encoding the data to a hex string (a more sophisticated solution would be to use base32).

```js
const PREFIX = 'my-app-';

function setPublicDragData(dataTransfer, data) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(data);
    let encoded = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        encoded += json.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
    }
    dataTransfer.setData(`${PREFIX}${encoded}`, '');
}

function getPublicDragData(dataTransfer) {
    for (const type of dataTransfer.types) {
        if (type.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
                const encoded = type.slice(PREFIX.length);
                let json = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i += 2) {
                    json += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(encoded.slice(i, i + 2), 16));
                }
                return JSON.parse(json);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can set the data in the `dragstart` event using `setPublicDragData(e.dataTransfer, data)` and retrieve it in the `dragenter`/`dragover` events using `getPublicDragData(e.dataTransfer)`.

Other than solutions using global variables or DOM elements, this solution should also work when dragging from one window to another.

Note that depending on your use case, you may want to add exception handling to the code (to handle invalid JSON). Also, I don't know what the size limit is.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I think you can get it by calling `e.relatedTarget`  See: http://help.dottoro.com/ljogqtqm.php</strike>

OK, I tried `e.target.previousElementSibling` and it works, sorta.... http://jsfiddle.net/Gz8Qw/4/ I think it hangs up because the event is being fired twice. Once for the div and once for the text node (when it fires for text node, it is `undefined`). Not sure if that will get you where you want to be or not...

Comment: Nope. [Try it for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/Gz8Qw/). In Chrome, `e.relatedTarget` is `null`. In Firefox, it's some odd `XrayWrapper`.

Comment: I did not get these results (for me it returned #dragTarget), but i realized this is still not what you were looking for.

Comment: Amending my previous comment: The `XrayWrapper` is a quirk of Firefox's development tools, appearing whenever you `console.log` a DOM element. In any event, what it wrapped around was the thing being moused over, not the draggable.

Comment: `e.target.previousElementSibling` only works because the `draggable` is the element before the drag target...

Comment: ahh, i see, i was thinking 'previous' in a different context. I see now that it is literally previous element in the DOM. I'm glad you're pointing all this out (instead of just leaving blank), helping me to understand as well - ty.

Comment: It would be nice if you could update to answer for people who don't read the comments. Thank you for your effort.