# HTML5 drag and drop wont drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, coffeescript

Playing with drag and drop and while I can seem to drag fine, I can't seem to drop.

Here's my playground:
http://jsfiddle.net/KZ8RD/1/

Basically, the `dragstart` and `dragend` events on the draggable node seem to fire fine.  But I have yet to trigger any event on that target nodes.

```
# Source handlers
$('#source')
  .on('dragstart', (e) -> log '#source dragstart', this, e)
  .on('dragend',   (e) -> log '#source dragend',   this, e)

# Target Handlers
$('#cells td')
  .on('dragenter', (e) -> log 'target dragenter',  this, e)
  .on('dragleave', (e) -> log 'target dragleave',  this, e)
  .on('dragover',  (e) -> log 'target dragover',   this, e)
  .on('drop',      (e) -> log 'target drop',       this, e)​​​
```

So what conditions need to exist for the target's `dragenter` and `drop` events to fire? I'm clearly missing some of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've been bitten by one of the [many quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html) of the HTML5 draggable API: You need to attach some data to the drag event, or else it will be ignored by potential drop targets. The fix is to add the line

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData 'text/html', 'foo'
```

to the `dragstart` event. (Note that `e.dataTransfer` won't work because the `dataTransfer` property isn't copied onto `e` by jQuery, at least as of 1.7.) Working fork of your playground: http://jsfiddle.net/AK2zJ/

Note that this will give you `dragenter` and `dragover`, but not `drop`... as the aforementioned article points out:

> For the drop event to fire at all, you have to cancel the defaults of both the dragover and the dragenter event.

You can do this in jQuery by returning `false` from each of those events. Here's an example with that modification as well, allowing the `drop` event to occur: http://jsfiddle.net/YaEBj/

In addition to this kludginess, it's worth mentioning that there are [serious flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065803/determine-what-is-being-dragged-from-dragenter-dragover-events) in the HTML5 draggable API. Really, the only good reason to use it (instead of something like jQuery UI) is if you want to enable drag-and-drop operations across multiple browser windows.

Comment: Interesting... That sort of data wouldn't always be required to do what you want, so it seems odd to require it.  Also, now `drop` wont fire (an in fact fires `dragleave` (wtf)) but that is probably another question entirely.