# Get the type of the element which is dragged at the moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

In my site there is a div which shows up if you drag something into the browser and disappears if you dropped it.

```
function startDraghandler() {
  $("*").on("dragover", function(event) {
    $("*").off("dragover");
    $("#uploadbox").animate({bottom:"+=360px"}, 250);
    $("*").on("mouseover", function() {
      $("#uploadbox").animate({bottom:"-=360px"}, 250);
      $("*").off("mouseover");
      startDraghandler();
    })
  });
}
```

But I don't want the div to show up if you dragged something from the site itself, only when it's coming from outside the browser. If you drag an element from the site, I want something different to happen. But I don't know how to do this, because all I've found on the internet is how to get the type of the dragged element when it's dropped.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[There is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065803/determine-what-is-being-dragged-from-dragenter-dragover-events) to know the data in the `dragEvents` except in the `dragStart` and `dragEnd` events.

But could exist a workaround, test this and tell me if it works ok for you:

```
// Variable declaration
var insidePage = false;

// When any element on document is dragged, set the var in true value.
$(document).on("dragstart", function(evt) {
    insidePage = true;
});

$(document).on("dragend", function(evt) {
    insidePage = false;
});

// Only executes the function if the element that is dragged is coming from outside the document
$(document).on("dragover", function(evt) {
  if(!insidePage){  
    // Code to drag from outside
  }
});
```