# event.dataTransfer.files length is 0

Tags: reactjs

I used e.dataTransfer to implement file drag and drop in React, but it says the length of the file list is 0.

```js
export default function App() {
  const dropRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    dropRef.current?.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
      console.log(e.dataTransfer?.files);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleImageDnd = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target.files);
  };

  const handleImageDragEnter = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.dataTransfer) console.log(e.dataTransfer.files);
  };

  const handleImageDragLeave = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={dropRef}
        onDragEnter={handleImageDragEnter}
        onDragLeave={handleImageDragLeave}
        style={{ width: '360px', height: '360px', border: '2px solid black' }}
      ></div>
      <form>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageDnd} />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

This is the same even with the onDrop property and the problem occurred in both browsers.

Comment: Maybe this helps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771177/detect-file-type-on-dragenter-cross-browser-solution)

Comment: tl;dr: You should use `drop` event. For some security reasons you cannot use `dragEnter` to get files informations